# How to handle Lync 2010 Clients updates

Tags: windows, update, sccm, lync

We have in a quite large Organization Lync 2010 deployed. Also we use for software and updates distribution System Center Configuration Manager.

Our problem we face is that, if we distribute the Lync 2010 client updates through SCCM’s update service, and the update gets applied the Lync 2010 client silently quits. Whatever someone for example is in a Call, IM, Conference … Of course you can think this not so good if the Manager is in an important call and suddenly the Lync client quits.

We surely could distribute the update late at night or in the night, but then we have the problem that not all client are power up since most users shut down their PC after they leave the office, and let me say “Wake On Lan” isn’t really an options there.

So I’m curios how others handle Lync Client Updates in their organization? Or what are the best practices in distributing them...

Thanks.

Martin.

Comment: Since the lync installer is actually an msi, shouldn't it be possible to use group policy to push this such that it is installed at the next boot cycle?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you just have to get creative!  A few ways you could handle this:

1. Gently: Set up an advertisement that is optional for the update.  The user will see that an update for Lync is available, but it can be installed at their discretion.  You can then run a compliance report, say, two weeks later and follow up with the stragglers.
2. Draconian: Do an advertisement like above, but set a mandatory deadline to enforce the update.  That way, users have the flexibility to install the update, but get schwacked with it if they wait too long.  You can make this a little nicer by sending out an email *warning* people about this...
3. Use a startup script: since your users typically power off their workstations at the end of the day, you can write a startup script that runs a WMI check to see if the update has been installed, and if not, run the install at that time.  The advantage to this is that the installer will run before the user gets the chance to start a conversation with the client.  If this is something you haven't done before, let me know and I can provide you with a sample script.

Of course, you can do a combination of these tactics to get complete coverage.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the "Only when no user is logged on" option. See the Environment tab of an Advertisement, the drop-down next to **Program can run:**